# invalid operands of types 'const char*' and const char[4]' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

I am getting the below error when I use the query to insert data in a database .

This is my code :

```
void Journal::insert_info()
{
    //Variables
    int id_journal= getId_journal();
    string nom_journal=getNom_journal();

//Here is where the error 
    string insert_query = "INSERT INTO `info_journal`(`id_journal`, `nom_journal`, `date`, `id_fournisseur`, `id_atm`, `state`, `state_parse_journal`, `terminal`, `id_utilisateur`) VALUES ('"+id_journal+"','"+nom_journal+"',NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL )";
    //int qstate = mysql_real_query(conn,insert_query.c_str(), strlen(insert_query.c_str()));
    query_state=mysql_query(conn, insert_query.c_str());
    if(!query_state)
    {

        cout << "Query Execution Problem " << mysql_errno(conn) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
         cout << endl << "success" << endl;
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: string literal doesn't have `operator +`

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks the error is removed now. And the query is executed correctly it dispay 'success' . But the data is not inserted in my table in the database.

Comment: This is probably a different issue. To be sure, you should single step debug (or print debug) that the `string insert_query` is what you expect it to be. If it still doesn't appear in the database, then you fixed the first bug and found the next.

Comment: @appleapple string literals (since they decay to a pointer) sure do have an `operator +(ptrdiff_t)`. They do not have an `operator +(const char *)`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow good point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error message says, you can't add pointers and arrays

The problematic part is:

```
"INSERT ..." + id_journal + "','"
```

Here the literal string `"INSERT ..."` will decay to a pointer (`const char*`) and then the value of `id_journal` is added. This result in the pointer `&(("INSERT ...")[id_journal]))`. In other words, the value of `id_journal` is used as an array index instead of being converted to a string.

You then try to add this pointer to the literal string `"','"` which is really a constant array of four characters (including the string null-terminator).

There no usable `+` operator which can handle this.

The simplest solution is to turn at least one of the operands of the first addition to a `std::string` object. I suggest the integer variable `id_journal` since you can't concatenate strings with integers (there's no automatic conversion here):

```
string insert_query = "INSERT ...VALUES ('" + std::to_string(id_journal) + "','" + ...;
```

This works because there is an overloaded `+` operator which takes a `const char*` on the left-hand side and a `std::string` on the right-hand side. Then once this is done, you have a `std::string` object which can be used for any further concatenations.

Comment: And I must admit, I still struggle to find the piece of code where `const char*` and `const char[4]` are added. The only part, I found is: `id_journal+"','"+nom_journal` but there is no `const char*` involved. It's suspicious somehow...

Comment: VALUES ('"+id_journal+"','"

Comment: @Scheff'sCat You're at the right place! The expression `"INSERT ..." + id_journal` results in the `const char*`, and then the literal string `"','"` is the `const char[4]` I'l rewrite my answer! :)

Comment: Yeah, got it myself. Adding a string literal with an `int` makes a `const char*`. And this is for sure _not_ what OP intended to achieve... ;-)

Comment: That string `"'.'"` is your char[4] I think. The `+id_journal` is also an error, as it will simply cause characters at the start of the `"INSERT INTO` to be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you're adding the **string literal**

```
"INSERT INTO `info_journal`(`id_journal`, `nom_journal`, `date`, `id_fournisseur`, `id_atm`, `state`, `state_parse_journal`, `terminal`, `id_utilisateur`) VALUES ('"
```

to an `int` named `id_journal` which results in a `const char*`.

Then you're trying to add this resulting `const char*` to the string literal `"','"` which is of type `const char[4]` but since there is no overloaded `operator+` which takes a `const char*` and an `const char` array you end up with the mentioned error saying :

```
invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [4]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I just had to convert the id_journal from int to string.

There is the solution and it works.

```
void Journal::insert_info()
{
    Db_response::ConnectionFunction();
    //Variables
    int id_journal= getId_journal();
    //string nom_journal=getNom_journal();
    string nom_journal = find_nom_journal();
    string s_id_journal(to_string(id_journal));

    string insert_query = "INSERT INTO `info_journal`(`id_journal`, `nom_journal`, `date`, `id_fournisseur`, `id_atm`, `state`, `state_parse_journal`, `terminal`, `id_utilisateur`) VALUES ('"+s_id_journal+"','"+nom_journal+"',' '  ,' ' ,' ' ,' ' ,' ' ,' ' ,' ' )";
    //int qstate = mysql_real_query(conn,insert_query.c_str(), strlen(insert_query.c_str()));
    query_state=mysql_query(conn, insert_query.c_str());
    if(!query_state)
    {

        cout << "Query Execution Problem " << mysql_errno(conn) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
         cout << endl << "success" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not working with c++ strings but simple C string literal when doing:

```
string insert_query = "INSERT INTO `info_journal`(`id_journal`, `nom_journal`, `date`, `id_fournisseur`, `id_atm`, `state`, `state_parse_journal`, `terminal`, `id_utilisateur`) VALUES ('"
                      + id_journal + "','" + nom_journal
                      + "',NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL )";
```

In that line the `"INSERT..."` decays to a `const char *` as will all the other C string constants. And `const char *` only has `operator +(ptrdiff_t)` that will advance the pointer.

What you can do is use C++ std::string literals like so and work with `std::string exclusively:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std::literals;

int id_journal = 42;
std::string nom_journal = "blub";

std::string insert_query = "INSERT INTO `info_journal`(`id_journal`, `nom_journal`, `date`, `id_fournisseur`, `id_atm`, `state`, `state_parse_journal`, `terminal`, `id_utilisateur`) VALUES ('"s
                           + std::string::to_string(id_journal)
                           + "','"s
                           + nom_journal
                           + "',NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL )"s;
```

Note: You have to convert `id_journal` and any other variable you want to append to the string to `std::string` first.